# how to read a value inside a loop?

Tags: java

i am trying to run a very simple java program. i want to  write a program that reads 10 integers and that the programs finds witch one is the maximum of them.
i wonder if is possible that inside a loop i can read the 10 values.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.out);
    int num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6, num7, num8, num9, num10;
        System.out.print(" please enter the numer "  +i);
             ===>num[i] = input.nextInt();//
```

i am trying to find the way to do it without using an array, since i haven't see this in school yet.
any idea how to do it inside a loop? or is just no possible to do?

Comment: Just use a 10 times loop, and save the max value, read a number and set that number like the max, and then read another compare with the last and update the max if correspond

Comment: yes, i agree with u, it is possible to do it that way. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you will have to create int array of 10 length and then read that intvalues in loop and process further.
Example :-

```
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.out).useDelimiter("\n");
int values[] = new int[10];
.
.
.


for ( int i = 0 ; i < values.length ; i++ ){
     System.out.print(" please enter the numer "  +i);
     values[i] = input.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sure it's possible.

All you have to do is keep the current maximum value, and then compare it to the value entered by the user for every new value he enters.
You can use the for loop to make sure it runs exactly 10 times.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is the maximum value, you don't need to store all ten inputs. So yes, this is possible without an array, and you don't need 10 integer variables either.

(Think about it a bit, you'll see that you can find the maximum in an array by scanning it once. Then you don't need the array anymore.)

Comment: yeah, is so true! just if is possible to do it, would you mind to share how with me. i really would like to know how to do it, even i don't  really need it for this particular exercise.

Comment: Just write the code as if you were trying to find the maximum in an array, except that you replace your `if (array[index] > max)` with `if (next input > max)`.